# Dual tensor in electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Is $F^{\mu\nu}$ not the dual tensor to $F_{\mu \nu}$?

I always thought that this was the case, but now I came across the dual tensor defined as
$\tilde{F}^{\mu \nu}=\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}F_{\rho \sigma}$.

Can somebody explain to me the difference?

Comment: I too have only seen $F^{\mu\nu}$ as the dual tensor of $F_{\mu\nu}$. Maybe this will help. I see people discuss what you are asking at the comments of an answer. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156857/

Comment: Since no one else has mentioned this, I believe $\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}$ is known as the Hodge dual of $F^{\mu\nu}$. Possible duplicate of this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37577/157014.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is not $F^{\mu\nu}$ the dual tensor to $F_{\mu\nu}$?

What you are calling dual above is essentially the [*musical isomorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) that identifies vectors and covectors when one has a metric tensor. In more common language in Physics it is the process of "raising and lowering indices". Two tensors related in this way are sometimes called *physically equivalent*, see e.g. ["General Relativity for Mathematicians" by Sachs & Wu](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461299059) for the usage of this terminology.

In your context, however, by "dual" one means more precisely the [*Hodge dual* of a differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator). Let me be more precise. A differential form is a totally skew-symmetric covariant tensor. If it has $k$-indices we call it a $k$-form. In a local coordinate system $x^\mu$ it has therefore components $\omega_{\mu_1\dots \mu_k}$ such that $$\omega_{[\mu_1\cdots \mu_k]}=\omega_{\mu_1\cdots \mu_k}\tag{1}$$

In this context, if one is working on a $d$-dimensional manifold (for physical spacetime $d=4$) one may define the *Hodge dual* of the $k$-form $\omega$ to be the $(d-k)$-form $\star \omega$ which has components $$(\star\omega)_{\mu_1\cdots \mu_{d-k}}=\dfrac{1}{k!}\epsilon^{\nu_1\cdots \nu_k}_{\phantom{\nu_1\cdots \nu_k}\mu_1\cdots \mu_{d-k}}\omega_{\nu_1\cdots \nu_k}.\tag{2}$$

The $\epsilon_{\mu_1\cdots \mu_d}$ are the components of a $d$-form which is called the *volume element* and which, in general, reads $$\epsilon_{\mu_1\cdots \mu_d} = \sqrt{-g}\varepsilon_{\mu_1\dots \mu_d},\tag{3}$$

where $\sqrt{-g}$ is the square root of the negative of the determinant of the metric tensor and where $\varepsilon_{\mu_1\dots \mu_d}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol with $d$ indices. In Minkowski spacetime with cartesian coordinates with the flat metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ this factor is equal to one and therefore the components of the volume element coincide with the components of the Levi-Civita symbol.

Finally, concerning the electromagnetic field, $\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}$ is nothing more than the Hodge dual of $F_{\mu\nu}$ with the indices raised: $$\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}=g^{\alpha \mu}g^{\beta \nu}(\star F)_{\alpha\beta}\tag{4}.$$ Notice that since one is working in $d = 4$ dimensions and since $F_{\mu\nu}$ is a $2$-form then its dual $\star F$ is a $2$-form as well.

Answer (score 2):

The covariant components (i.e. with lower indexes)
of the [electromagnetic field tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor#Relationship_with_the_classical_fields)
expressed by the electric field $\vec{E}$ and magnetic field $\vec{B}$
(with $c$ being the speed of light) are
$$F_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0     &  E_x/c &  E_y/c &  E_z/c \\
-E_x/c &  0     & -B_z   &  B_y   \\
-E_y/c &  B_z   &  0     & -B_x   \\
-E_z/c & -B_y   &  B_x   &  0
\end{pmatrix}. \tag{1}$$

The contravariant component (i.e. with upper indexes) of the same tensor are
$$F^{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0     & -E_x/c & -E_y/c & -E_z/c \\
 E_x/c &  0     & -B_z   &  B_y   \\
 E_y/c &  B_z   &  0     & -B_x   \\
 E_z/c & -B_y   &  B_x   &  0
\end{pmatrix}. \tag{2}$$

The transformation between the covariant and contravariant components
is done by the usual index lowering/raising with the metric $\eta$.
$$F_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\alpha}F^{\alpha\beta}\eta_{\beta\nu}$$

From comparing (1) and (2) you see,
the covariant and contravariant components
differ only by the sign of the electric field components
in the time-row and time-column.

The dual tensor is a completely different thing.
Using the definition $\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\rho\sigma}$,
the definition (1), and the definition of the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Four_dimensions) $\epsilon$
you get
$$\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0   & -B_x   & -B_y   & -B_z   \\
 B_x &  0     &  E_z/c & -E_y/c \\
 B_y & -E_z/c &  0     &  E_x/c \\
 B_z &  E_y/c & -E_x/c &  0
\end{pmatrix}. \tag{3}$$
(I strongly recommend you verify this on paper.)

Comparing (3) with (2) you see,
the dual tensor $\tilde{F}$ and the original tensor $F$
essentially differ by the exchange of electric field with magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes $\tilde{F} ^{\mu \nu}$ is the (Hodge) dual of the field strength tensor, defined conventionally with a factor of a half in comparison to your equation,
$$\tilde{F} ^{\mu \nu}:= 1/2\, \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} F_{\alpha \beta}. $$
So I'm wondering whether the issue is the language used. What did you understand before hand by "dual?"

If the confusion is just about raising or lowering indices note that (no tildes)
$$F^{\mu \nu} = g^{\mu \alpha} g^{\nu \beta} F_{\alpha \beta} $$
Simply uses the metric to change the position of indices.